# Problem with toggling black screen option in PowerPoint 2010 through VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to determine how to black/unblack a Powerpoint presentation using VBA.  I modified a VBA Macro that I found online (http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780470634004/670?bookview=search -- "Mastering VBA for Microsoft Office 2010; page 670")

```
Sub Test1()
    With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View
        .State = ppSlideShowBlackScreen
        .State = ppSlideShowRunning
    End With
End Sub
```

Setting the state to `ppSlideShowBlackScreen` does indeed make the screen go black.  According to the book, "To toggle the black screen or white screen off and start the show running again, set the State property to `ppSlideShowRunning`".

If I run this in PPT 2007, it works as expected - it almost looks like nothing happened (I imagine the screen goes black for a fraction of a second & then returns to normal).  Commenting out the second line does show a black screen, which shows that this is working as expected.

However, if I run this macro in PPT 2010 the screen goes black & stays black.  No matter what I set the state to, I can't make the screen revert to its original state.

- I tried `ppSlideShowWhiteScreen` & it shows a completely white screen, but that's it.
- I tried `ppSlideShowPaused` as well, but it didn't do anything

If I use the "Black" screen option from the PPT menu, the screen goes black & the option changes to "Unblack" screen.  Using this does revert the screen back to normal.  Also, using the keyboard shortcut ("b") will toggle between black & normal mode.

So, there must be a way to do this in PPT 2010, but for some reason the VBA method isn't working correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's definetely a bug in PowerPoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Test1()
    With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View
        .State = ppSlideShowBlackScreen
        If ppSlideShowDone Then
        .State = ppSlideShowWhiteScreen
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Explanation would make the answer much better

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling I found that sending the 'b' key to the SlideShowWindow was the only solution.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Activate
SendKeys "b", False
DoEvents
Application.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Otaku is right - it's just a bug in PPT.  I haven't heard anything on the MSDN forums about this either, so I'm willing to accept that.  Thanks to everyone who had a look at the question.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2010 it works for me going to next then to previous slide and then returning to "Running" mode.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowBlackScreen

...do some stuff in "invisible" mode,
something like "screenupdating set to false" in excel or word...

'Unblack or unwhite screen
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Previous
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.State = ppSlideShowRunning
```